# Linking taxonomy terms that appear in content

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Is there a way to find and link to taxonomy terms that appear within content?

Comment: How are you displaying terms?

Comment: Terms within the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean automatically? You probably want something like the [glossary module](http://drupal.org/project/glossary)

> The glossary module scans posts for glossary terms (including
>   synonyms). The glossary indicator is inserted after every found term,
>   or the term itself is turned into an indicator depending on the site
>   settings. ... The glossary uses Drupal's built in taxonomy feature, so
>   you can organize your terms in a Drupal vocabulary.